# Can I Have Multiple Hidden Views In A ViewController?

Tags: ipad, menu, subview

I know, this seems a bad solution, but I can't think or figured out how to make something better.
What I need to do is like a menu, iPad menu, with a toolbar up and bottom, and an image in the background. In the bottom toolbar, I'm going to have 4 different buttons. Every button is going to create the options menu in the middle of the screen. One button needs to display 3 options (buttons with images), another 4 options, another 8 options (for this, I'm going to use Scroll View and Page Control, because I'm going to need 2 pages), another 2 options. 
I was trying to use subviews, one subview for every button, and I was added the options in the subviews. When I select one button, its subview was loaded, but when I tried to change its position and size, its buttons was missed, the subview was empty...
Now I'm going to have the 4 subviews in the ViewController, but hidden. When I select one button, the view is going to appear, and the others views are going to have hidden. This means, that all the subviews are going to have loaded. Is this convenient? 
Is this method requires a lot of memory?
If somebody have another and better solution, I'll be completely grateful...
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple hidden subviews within a view controller, but I don't think it's the most practical way of going about it.

You mention that the menus are to appear in the center of the screen. In this case, I think a better approach would be to create a separate view controller for each of your menus and then have your main view controller present them modally by using the view controller's `modalPresentationStyle` property. By doing this, you're saving yourself a ton of time by not having to write code that checks for which views are hidden and which aren't; you're letting the API do its job, so at most you'll need to implement a few methods such as `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`.

Check out Apple's [documentation about UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and more specifically the section called "Presenting Another View Controller's Content".

Comment: Thank you very much. So, you tell me that I should do one XIB for every menu and this XIB is going to be loaded inside my main view controller? Like a sub-viewController?

Comment: Yes, each menu would use its own xib, and by extension, each menu would have its own view controller which would load this xib in its corresponding init method. Your bottom menu would then load the appropriate view controller, which in turn then loads its xib.

Comment: Oh, thank you, that seems a better solution. Just one maybe silly question, can this view controller be transparent? Because I need that looks like I just add the buttons, I mean, the screen have a background image, that just can be cluttered by the buttons, not by the whole "subViewController"

Comment: This should be possible. When you create the xibs for the menus, set their background colors as transparent; I don't recall if there's an option in Interface Builder for this, but if not, add this to the init method for each menu's view controller: [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; I should also point out that the dismissModalViewController is deprecated, didn't notice that at first. Apple have recommended using dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: instead.

Comment: Oh, Thank You very much. As you can see, I'm a beginner... I'll start to make some research about dismissViewControllerAnimated... Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi. I did what you told me. I create another XIB, and change its size in the IB, to cover just one part of the Screen (and no cover the toolbars). I drag 2 buttons, just to test. Now with the first button of the toolbar, I call the ViewController (code below), and now the screen is all cover and black, my new XIB does not appear...

Comment: -(IBAction)showFirstMenu{
MenuAllEntriesViewController *menuAE = [[MenuAllEntriesViewController alloc] init];
[menuAE setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
[self presentModalViewController:menuAE animated:YES];
}

Comment: Hi, I already solved that problem... But my view covers all the screen and it's not transparent :/

Comment: Hmmm... if it's not showing up transparent, I'm not sure what the problem could be.

As for it taking up the whole screen, try setting the view controller's modalPresentationStyle to UIModalPresentationFormSheet, and be sure to switch out presentModalViewController:animated to presentViewController:animated:completion:, as the modal one has been deprecated.